# Automate Trello to convert checklist item to card AND replace item with hyperlink to card

Tags: trello

## I would like to automate Trello so that:

this **TRIGGER:**

> when I convert a checklist item into a new card

results in this **ACTION:**

> a link to the new card is added to the checklist *(in place of the converted item)*

---

I've looked at Butler and IFTTT but neither seem capable of doing this *(although I'll be happily proven wrong)*.

---

#### Edit:

This looked promising: [3 – Create cards from checklist items](https://inspiriting.biz/tame-your-trello-chaos/) but as far as I can tell the options are not available for me :-(

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @DavidPostill Um, really - how is this question vague or broad? I've provided a very specific TRIGGER and ACTION. I'm NOT asking for a script writing service. I mentioned that I've tried IFTTT _(IF This Then That)_ and an app called Butler specifically for Trello.  I'm led to believe Butler is capable to this type of automation, but I'm at a loss as how to achieve it. I'm looking for an out of the box turn key solution.... just saying

Comment: @DavidPostill - I just found the answer, would you kindly take this question off hold so that I may answer it.  Thanks

Comment: Webapps are off topic here and should be asked at [webapps.se]. This question is currently too old to migrate.

Answer (score 0):

When I first added Butler to Trello only some of the TRIGGERS and ACTIONS were available.

To get more control I needed to complete a 2nd step by inviting the Butler Bot to my board. I found it on this link: https://butlerfortrello.com/dashboard.html.

Doing this provided many more options and allowed me setup the required TRIGGER & ACTION.

---

For what it's worth the solution was not *exactly* what I thought, but very much meets my needs. Here is a screen shot:
[image]